# Passing configuration to Spark Job

Tags: apache-spark

I'd like to have an external config file that I'd pass to SparkJobs. Assuming I'm running my job from an assembly and config file in on my local filesystem:

```
spark-class my.assembly.jar my_application.conf
```

It would be great if I could access config file in spark job, but its not possible, its main method is executed on another node.

I've been trying to use --files argument for spark-class, but this does not seem to work.

Similar behavior (to --files) tried in spark repl ends with error:

```
val inFile = sc.textFile(SparkFiles.get("conf.a"))
inFile.first()
```

The above assumes file *conf.a* has been passed to spark-class with --files option.

Any thoughts on this problem? How to fix the issue? I'd really like to use external file as configuration source.

I'm using apache-spark-0.9.0

Comment: Found this tutorial: http://docs.sigmoidanalytics.com/index.php/Using_the_Spark_Shell - and it quite resembles the way I try to set things up, unfortunately it does not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sc.addFile(path)` to make your file visible to all the nodes:

```
object MySparkApp extends App {
  override def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val sc = new SparkContext("local", "MySparkApp", "/opt/spark", jarOfObject(this.getClass))

    sc.addFile(args(1))

    val rdd = sc.textFile(SparkFiles.get("conf.a"))
  }
}

> sbt run MySparkApp /tmp/conf.a
```

Note that when using `SparkFiles.get(path)` I'm only giving the file name, not the full path: this is because the file comes from my local filesystem, so it will be copied to the job working directory.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest is to load the file into **HDFS** *cluster*. The tutorial you linked assumes that file is present in **HDFS** & hence can be accessed across the *cluster*. If you cannot then `addfile` argument given by **Freidereikhs** will work for you but then you have to bundle the `conf` file with the application.